# Reporting tool (Crystal Reports, Infomaker, ...) for Jhipster apps?

Tags: spring-boot, crystal-reports, jhipster, reporting

We created a Jhipster web application, we have some data that we need to share through documents (invoices for eg.) 
My question is, is there any reporting tool for Jhipster (works fine with jhipster apps) ? 
Anything like Crystal reports or Infomaker.

Thank you

Comment: It should not be specific to JHipster , anything that works for a Spring Boot app would work.

Comment: Great, thank you for you reactivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JasperReports is a good option to generate reports from Java/Spring applications. You can design the report using a visual editor (called Jaspersoft Studio), and then put the report file (.jrxml) in the classpath of your JHipster application (src/main/resources) and invoke the Jasper engine to fill the report by passing the data as a Java object or JSON string. Using the same report design file as an input, the library allows you to export to multiple output formats (PDF, HTML, Excel, etc).

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, i tried this many ways, but never got any result, i followed couple videos on youtube, can't figure it out too. 

Created a jrxml file (data source is jhipster postgres database)

Do you have an example of how to integrate this on Jhipster ? 

Thank you